# Filling area under two bezier curves on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

This is my first time using html canvas, and I am a little stumped with this one. I am trying to build an image like this on an html canvas:

Html canvas

[image]

This is what I have tried so far, and I can't seem to fill the areas beneath the lines with the appropriate color. in particular, I tried `context.fill();`.

Here is a stackblitz of the working example that I have, minus the fills beneath the lines.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-troahu?file=index.js

Answer (score 3):

To be able to fill something on the canvas you actually need to define that area **completely**. If you just mimic the look of the curves, you have an open path only and it merely fills the 'area' that lies in-between the start & end point.

[image]

The fix is simple though - just add two more straight lines [C, D] that make up the rectangular shape below the curve and you're good to go.

[image]

Here's a working example based on your stackblitz code (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


function drawCurve(x, y, curves, canvasColor, strokeStyle) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  for (let i = 0; i < curves.length; i++) {
    let c = curves[i];
    context.quadraticCurveTo(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]);
  }
  context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.lineTo(0, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = canvasColor;
  context.fill();
}
drawCurve(
  0,
  45, [
    [75, 27, 173, 44],
    [240, 50, 300, 35]
  ],
  "#98dbcc"
);
drawCurve(
  0,
  35, [
    [65, 65, 125, 45],
    [197, 20, 300, 45]
  ],
  "#00a780"
);
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem Anyela - glad I could help! =) By the way, if you think this is the correct answer, please consider accepting the answer using the 'tick' button.